# Mat and Bmat in C++

Tags: c++, c, linear-algebra

I have a function with a 'mat' and 'bmat' in c++ that uses ittp libraries. I couldn't find what these functions do, but I want to implement same functions as mat and bmat in C this time. I'm struggling to understand the functionality as I'm new to programming in C, C++

Comment: @ElRuso I am not sure this is the correct reason to downvote here.

Comment: @KamiKaze i'm not downvoting question, but ok may be better reason is http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @ElRuso Then again to write that you downvoted while you actually didn't seems confusing

Comment: @KamiKaze hmm, i'm not sure what you want to tell me. if you will look  in official SO guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you will see the same things like on http://idownvotedbecau.se/ but not so detailed and understandable for newbies

Comment: @ElRuso you said you did not downvote but the link name says that you downvoted. Also it is nice to link to some explanation why this is not a good question but only posting comments appears rude to some people. Just to let you know

Comment: @KamiKaze are you trying to follow this links? it's exactly `link to some explanation why this is not a good question`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170620/discussion-between-kami-kaze-and-el-ruso).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick and Hassle-free Installation & Usage of IT++ library on Linux/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077559/quick-and-hassle-free-installation-usage-of-it-library-on-linux-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I took your question for **how to implement matrix manipulating algorithm in *C/C++***.

Because ***Java*** syntax resemble that of ***C/C++***, I highly recommend you take a look at the following files from LWJGL repository:

1. [Matrix.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/8bb7dfefc628972e71568fac243503d8984555fc/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix.java)
2. [Matrix2f.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/8bb7dfefc628972e71568fac243503d8984555fc/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix2f.java)
3. [Matrix3f.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/8bb7dfefc628972e71568fac243503d8984555fc/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix3f.java)
4. [Matrix4f.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/8bb7dfefc628972e71568fac243503d8984555fc/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.java)
5. [GLMatrix.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/8bb7dfefc628972e71568fac243503d8984555fc/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/opengles/util/GLMatrix.java)